# Why the result of db.user.count() is 0 in mongo?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

as you can see in the image below I just create an user even though it still gave 0 , and the same thing with collections when I run show collection it shows me one , but when when I do db.collection.count() gave me 0.[image]

the image for db.collection.count()

[image]

I do have one document on this collection here is image from Mongo compass
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. As you can see there is no "user" collection in this database , there is only one collection and its name is "Databases_for_tp" so counting documents in not existing collection will show always 0.
2. You misenterpreted the meaniing of count() command , it counts how many documents there is in single collection , not how many collections there is in  chosen database.
3. You can find the users when you create them in the admin database even they are created to authenticate in different database.

check:

```
 use admin
 show collections
 db.system.users.count()
```

Note also it is a good practice to add code as text and not as pictures so it is easier to interpret.

Comment: Actually I do have documents on this collection I will update the questions to show the document, thank you for your helps and your advice

Comment: I just tried "db.system.users.count()" and it's gaved me 0 too

Comment: Indeed there is 1 document in the collection with name Databases_for_tp